# Using ESP32 as a web server and Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp32

This is my first project and I'm getting my way around this.

I wanted to make a simple project using Arduino creating a web server, in order to turn on and off the AC.

I think I made a mistake buying ESP 32 cause I wanted Wifi functionality and didn't realised this is not a simple shield for arduino.

So what I got so far are:

1.Arduino Uno

1. ESP 32
2. Ir transmitter
3. IR receiver

Guys can I still use the ESP32 with arduino?
I understand I can use only ESP32 for this but unfortunately this project is for Arduino Course at my college and I'm afraid ESP32 wont be accepted as a project.

Comment: If I were asking this question I would do a quick web search for “ESP32 Arduino” and maybe ask my instructor if it could be accepted.

Comment: `I'm afraid ESP32 wont be accepted as a project.` ... what does this mean? ... do you not know if it will be accepted?